How to use BindProperty to bind complex property of an HTML select element
Suppose I have the following model
public class MyModel {
    public ProgramModel(Guid id, string name, string description, Currency currency) {
        Id = id;
        Name = name;
        Description = description;
        Currency = currency;
    }

    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public Currency Currency { get; set; }
}

The type Currency is
public class Currency {
    public Currency(string numericCode, string code, string name) {
        NumericCode = numericCode;
        Code = code;
        Name = name;
    }

    public string NumericCode { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

Usage example
var currency = new Currency("978", "EUR", "Euro");

Within my Razor page model class I have
[BindProperty]
public MyModel MyModel { get; set; }

[BindProperty]
public IEnumerable<Currency> AllCurrencies { get; set; }

Thanks to this i can render a select item in the view with code similar to this one
<select class="form-select" asp-for="MyModel.Currency">
    @foreach (var currency in Model.AllCurrencies) {
        if (currency.Code == Model.MyModel.Currency.Code) {
            <option value="??????" data-numericcode="@currency.NumericCode" 
               data-code="@currency.Code" data-name="@currency.Name" selected="">
               @currency.Name</option>
        }
        else {
            <option value="??????" data-numericcode="@currency.NumericCode" 
               data-code="@currency.Code" data-name="@currency.Name">
               @currency.Name</option>
        }
    }
</select>

Is there any way to instruct the model binder to recreate the Currency object when a different option item is selected on the client?


Is there any way to instruct the model binder to recreate the Currency object when a different option item is selected on the client?

You can add hidden fields in the form to pass the properties of Currency like:
        <select id="currencySelect" class="form-select" asp-for="MyModel.Currency" onchange="updateCurrencyFields()">
            @foreach (var currency in Model.AllCurrencies)
            {
                if (currency.Code == Model.MyModel.Currency.Code)
                {
                    <option value="??????" data-numericcode="@currency.NumericCode"
                            data-code="@currency.Code" data-name="@currency.Name" selected="">
                        @currency.Name
                    </option>
                }
                else
                {
                    <option value="??????" data-numericcode="@currency.NumericCode"
                            data-code="@currency.Code" data-name="@currency.Name">
                        @currency.Name
                    </option>
                }
            }
        </select>
        <input type="hidden" asp-for="MyModel.Currency.NumericCode" id="NumericCode" />
        <input type="hidden" asp-for="MyModel.Currency.Code" id="Code"/>
        <input type="hidden" asp-for="MyModel.Currency.Name" id="Name"/>
    </div>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

<script>
    function updateCurrencyFields() {
        var select = document.getElementById("currencySelect");

        var numericcode = select.options[select.selectedIndex].getAttribute("data-numericcode");
        var code = select.options[select.selectedIndex].getAttribute("data-code");
        var name = select.options[select.selectedIndex].getAttribute("data-name");

        document.getElementById("NumericCode").value = numericcode;
        document.getElementById("Code").value = code;
        document.getElementById("Name").value = name;
    }
</script>

And code in the MyCurrencyPageModel like:
public class MyCurrencyPageModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
    public MyCurrencyPageModel(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    [BindProperty]
    public MyModel MyModel { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<Currency> AllCurrencies { get; set; }

    public void OnGet()
    {
        AllCurrencies = _context.Currencies.ToList();
        MyModel = new MyModel(Guid.NewGuid(), "Example Program", "Description", AllCurrencies.First());
    }

    public IActionResult OnPost()
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return Page();
        }

        MyModel.Id = Guid.NewGuid(); 

        var item = _context.Currencies.Where(v=>v.Code ==MyModel.Currency.Code).FirstOrDefault();
        MyModel.Currency = item;

        _context.MyModels.Add(MyModel);
        _context.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToPage("Index");
    }
}

With the test result:



